# Getting keys of an 'Association'

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, associations

Suppose you have an association of the type:

```
a = {1, 0, 0, 0}; b = {0, 1, 0, 0}; c = {0, 0, 1, 0}; d = {0, 0, 0, 1}; e = {2, 0, 0, 0};
f = {0, 2, 0, 0}; g = {0, 0, 2, 0}; h = {0, 0,0, 2};
assoc = Association[1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> e, 6 -> f, 7 -> g, 8 -> h]

(*=> <|1 -> {1, 0, 0, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1, 0, 0}, 3 -> {0, 0, 1, 0}, 4 -> {0, 0, 0, 1},
 5 -> {2, 0, 0, 0}, 6 -> {0, 2, 0, 0}, 7 -> {0, 0, 2, 0}, 8 -> {0, 0, 0, 2}|> *)
```

In general, the association may contain many more terms.
You can access the keys, given the values using `PositionIndex`, e.g.:

```
PositionIndex[assoc][{2, 0, 0, 0}]
(*=> {5} *)
```

Suppose the output of a calculation is of the form:

```
-0.2*{0, 1, 0, 0} + 0.4*{2, 0, 0, 0} + 0.11*{0, 0, 2, 0} + 0.7*{0, 0, 1, 0}
```

How can you get a list of pairs where the pair consists of the coefficient and the corresponding key of the element of `assoc`? I.e., for the above output, how can you create the following list?

```
{{-0.2, 2}, {0.4, 5}, {0.11, 7}, {0.7,3}}
```

Comment: You could start by turning the association around: `assoc2 = Association@KeyValueMap[#2 -> #1 &, assoc]` gives `<|{1, 0, 0, 0} -> 1, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 2, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 3, {0, 0, 0, 1} -> 4, {2, 0, 0, 0} -> 5, {0, 2, 0, 0} -> 6, {0, 0, 2, 0} -> 7, {0, 0, 0, 2} -> 8|>`, which can then be used more easily to do what you want.

Comment: Also, `-0.2*{0, 1, 0, 0} + 0.4*{2, 0, 0, 0} + 0.11*{0, 0, 2, 0} + 0.7*{0, 0, 1, 0}` will be immediately evaluated to `-0.2*{0, 1, 0, 0} + 0.4*{2, 0, 0, 0} + 0.11*{0, 0, 2, 0} + 0.7*{0, 0, 1, 0}`, so that format is not ideal

Comment: You must have some code that assembles the output above. However, as @Hausdorff mentioned, the output will at once be simplified. Therefore, instead of assemble an output that looses information, assemble directly what you want: {{-0.2, 2}, {0.4, 5}...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You are right. Suppose `{1,0,0,0}` etc have `Symbol` as `Head`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, as *@Hausdorff* mentioned, you won't get `-0.2*{0, 1, 0, 0} + 0.4*{2, 0, 0, 0} + 0.11*{0, 0, 2, 0} + 0.7*{0, 0, 1, 0}` as output due to immediate evaluation. But if this is only a simplified example of yours and you're somehow able to preserve the elements in the output, try something like this:

```
assoc = Association[1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> e, 6 -> f, 
   7 -> g, 8 -> h];
iassoc = GeneralUtilities`AssociationInvert[assoc]
Cases[-0.2 b + 0.4*e - 0.11*g + 0.7*c, x_*y_ :> {x, iassoc[y]}]
```

> `{{-0.2, 2}, {0.7, 3}, {0.4, 5}, {-0.11, 7}}`

(It's recommended you post your original data format so that more specific answers can be given!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `Cases[-0.2 b + 0.4*e - 0.11*g + 0.7*c, x_*y_ :> {x, iassoc[y]}]` was the line I needed.